# What's the differences between "!" and "?" operators in dart null safety?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Could anyone explain a little bit about the differences between
using this:

```dart
final block = blocks?.first;
```

and this:

```dart
final block = blocks!.first;
```

where `blocks` is:

```
List<Block>? blocks
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In short, the first line of code will return `null` if blocks is `null` and the second line will `throw an exception` if blocks is `null`.

When you use `blocks?.first`, the value of `blocks` can be ***null***, but when you use `blocks!.first`, you inform the compiler that you are certain that `blocks` are ***not null***.

`final block = blocks!.first;` means you are completely assured that `List<Block>? blocks` is initialized before block assignment.

also in `final block = blocks?.first;`, `block` will be ***nullable***, but in `final block = blocks!.first;`, `block` is ***not nullable***.

```dart
  List<Block>? blocks;
  ...
  // you are not sure blocks variable is initialized or not.
  // block is nullable.
  // return null if blocks is null.
  final Block? block = blocks?.first;

  // you are sure blocks variable is initialized.
  // block is not nullable.
  // throw an error if blocks is null.
  final Block block = blocks!.first;
```

Comment: So simple and nice. Thank you.